USB Ethernet and normal ethernet is not working on ubuntu desktop 24.04
I previously had problems with normal ethernet on the laptop that im currently using and i assumed it was the hardware fault so i ordered a new adapter(that works on other devices) and tried using it on ubuntu and the error i get is the same one i get trying to connect with normal ethernet : "activation of network connection failed." this is a fresh install of ubuntu if i need to give outputs of any commands just ask
ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9e:94:f5:e7:2e:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:d9:87:8a:90:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enx00e04c68425d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:42:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::9ae9:7167:33ca:b5db/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


edit:
the wired connection in the top right just says connecting...
lsusb (wifi disabled trying to connect via usb ethernet):
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. Centrino Bluetooth Wireless Transceiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2984 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. Wireless Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:81a3 Dell Computer Corp. Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


lsmod | grep 815:
r8153_ecm              12288  0
cdc_ether              24576  2 r8153_ecm,cdc_ncm
usbnet                 61440  4 cdc_mbim,r8153_ecm,cdc_ncm,cdc_ether
r8152                 143360  1 r8153_ecm
mii                    20480  2 usbnet,r8152


Item 4 has a valid LAN IP Address.  What is the IP Address of your default gateway?

@eyoung100 i have no clue I would just say it's the default 192.168.0.1 also the 6th item is the USB adapter and eno1 is the built in port that I think doesn't work

Why are you wanting to use Item 6 when Item 4 has a valid IP address for your LAN?  Remove the USB adapter, reboot, and reissue the ip -a command, then ping -c4 192.168.0.1  Edit your question to include that output

@eyoung100 my bad, when I was using the ip a command I was connected to the internet via WiFi and that's the item 4. wifi works completely fine however I want to change to Ethernet for a more stable connection. I will edit the ip a command from when im not connected via WiFi

OK and I'm going to assume Item 2 is the supposed broken Ethernet adapter?  Do you want to troubleshoot 2 or 6?

@eyoung100 tried troubleshooting 2 already didnt work so lets go with 6!

Please add the output of sudo lsusb | grep ethernet to your question.  I need to determine the driver for the Realtek USB based NIC.  I'm hoping the driver has not been dropped from the kernel, the Realtek 8192u chipset.

@eyoung100 the output is blank. there is nothing displayed when i issue the command

Try just sudo lsusb and copy/paste the entry for the adapter.  I probably grepped the wrong string.

@eyoung100 done

See Answer below.

Troubleshooting
I'm going to assume this laptop also has Windows.  If not, please ignore the following step:
From Windows

Disconnect the USB adapter and Disable the Wireless network adapter.
Plug the ethernet cable into the built-in ethernet port
From an Administrator's Command Prompt issue: ipconfig /all

If the built-in ethernet port of your Dell is in fact broken, it will return a self-assigned APIPA address in the form of 169.254.x.x, which indicates that the card/port is malfunctioning or the port the card is plugged into in your ISP modem/router is bad.


Disable the built-in ethernet port from your laptops firmware (This will prevent it from trying to connect in both Windows and Ubuntu, even though it's broken.  This makes it easier on us in Ubuntu to add the USB network adapter.

From Ubuntu

Make sure the USB adapter is unplugged.
See the last bullet in the Windows Section if you do not have Windows, as the malfunctioning card needs to be disabled/off in both cases
Disable the WiFi Adapter also.  This will prevent the infinite Connecting loop.
Plug the Adapter in.  The driver is included in the kernel.  If it doesn't connect disable TLP


tried it. went into bios disabled the built-in ethernet. turned off wifi in ubuntu and tried connecting via the usb adapter. did not work. tried disabling TLP. did not work either. the laptop is only running ubuntu.

With The Wireless Disabled and the broken port off, the only card left is the USB card.  Does ip -a report anything new besides having less numbers?

edited the output however i dont think anything changed. also this may help but the wired connection stops the "connecting..." after a while and i have to turn of and on again for it to display the same message as earlier. i got pretty much the same things from when i tried to fix the built in ethernet port. the same error message and pretty much everything.

What is the Ethernet Cable connected to?  ip -a is properly returning no assigned IP for any device in the list, which is what I want tp see.  Type lsmod | grep 815.  Let's see if the module loaded?

edited the post with the output. the Ethernet cable is connected to the Ethernet port on the adapter and the adapter is connected to my laptop via usb

Where's the other end connected? Consider the following: Laptop -> USB Adapter -> Ethernet Cable -> ???? Fill-in the Question Marks.

Yippee The Driver loaded.  Now we need to find out why its not communicating....  I have a feeling the port that the ????'s fill in is bad.

straight to the port in the router I can try another cable and I'll let you know if it works

plugged in my ethernet cable that goes to my pc and nothing changed also this cable is plugged in the same way as the other one

could this be maybe a router problem? maybe my router is somehow blocking the connection?

How many ports are on your Router?  Also, is the router plugged into a Modem/Router Combo or just a plain modem from your ISP?

there are 4 ports and im sure that the one im using is working and also ive tried the other ones its a modem router combo (tp link archer of some kind i belive?)

Call your ISP: Ask for Second Tier Support -> Ask the Support Tech if your MAC Address is tracked in the Bridge Table.  If they say Yes, ask them if the MAC Address for your Dell NIC (the one we disabled in the firmware, in the form ww:xx:yy:zz. Write it down if you need to), and if it is there have them REMOVE IT.  Tell them it broke, and you need your connection rebuilt in the bridge table.  If it isn't there, we can keep troubleshooting.

it is not are you sure there is nothing i could change in the router settings that might be blocking my connection? almost identical thing happened when i tried to connect via the built-in ethernet port

Disconnect everything from the router that goes to the LAN, so that the only thing connected is the connection from the ISP.  Reconnect the laptop in the first empty port.  See if it connects, ping something and then disable the Connection in Network Manager. Unplug the Ethernet Cable and move to the next router port.  Perform the steps again.  Do this for all four ports.  If any are bad you're eligible for a new modem. If you need the steps written in more than a comment let me know.
